# Objective C: Orientation Change With UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to make an app with UIScrollView (pagingEnabled) that should adapt on the device's interface orientation.

to do this, i made two UIScrollViews loaded with UIImageviews and UIButtons inside and animations (CA). one for portrait and the other one for landscape (you'll see it in my code).

now my problem is whenever i rotate the device, yes! it respond to the orientation change but it goes back to the first page.

ok picture this... you are already on the 10th page of the scrollView in portrait then when you switched to landscape it is on the first page again.

i hope explained it clearly.

and... it crashes on iPad when i rotate it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        //self.view = portraitView;
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:YES andDuration:duration];

    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        //self.view = landscapeView;
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:NO andDuration:duration];
    }
}

- (void) changeTheViewToPortrait:(BOOL)portrait andDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    if(portrait){
        //change the view and subview frames for the portrait view
        [self forPortrait];
        [self removeMainSVLContents];
    }
    else{   
        //change the view and subview  frames for the landscape view
        [self forLandscape];
        [self removeMainSVPContents];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

What's inside "forPortrait" is the same as in "forLandscape" they just have different frames  and it has different images too that will fit the screen on portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

at the time of the animation use `**scrollRectToVisible:animated:**` method to show or stay on the desire place of scroll view
may this will be useful to you.